# Why can an address extend an interface with unimplemented function inside? And the function still works!

Tags: solidity

I was watching this video:
https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZeFjGJpzI7E&feature=shares

but there's a magic trick I don't understand. Let's take the following extract of the code:

```
interface Token {
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external;

    function transferFrom(address, address, uint256) external;
}

contract KM {
    event Start(uint256 auctionNumber);
    event Bid(address indexed sender, uint256 amount);
    event End(address[] bidderList);
    Token public tokenToBeAttributed;
    uint256 public endAt;
    bool public started;
    bool public ended;
    string tokenID;
    address[] bidderList;
    address corporateAddress;
    mapping(address => uint256) public bids;
    uint256 public totalBiddedAmount;
    uint256 public auctionNumber;

    constructor(    
        address _tokenToBeAttributed,
        string memory _tokenID,
        address _coporateAddress
    ) {
        tokenToBeAttributed = Token(_tokenToBeAttributed);
        tokenID = _tokenID;
        corporateAddress = _coporateAddress;
    }
```

How can `transfer` and `safeTransfer` work! I tried and it works even though the contract is not using Open Zeppelin or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast an `address` to any interface, like a `Duck Typing` - you can say the compiler - I know there are such methods, so that at compilation they are converted to the method signatures and the call will be executed.

In the `interface` you can have fewer methods as in reality the contract implements, or even some extra methods, which are not implemented, but until you don't call non existed methods you are OK.

So implementation doesn't matter, just the interface in cross-contract calls.

Comment: Crazy but in this example there appears to be no implementation of safeTransferFrom and transferFrom. What am I missing? Like how does Solidity know what these function do?

Comment: Implementation is in the previously deployed contract - the `_tokenToBeAttributed`. Аnalogy - think about `contracts` like the different API endpoints. The `address` is the URL for that API. The `interface` is like the `swagger` **schema** of that endpoint.